# Problem with Google Maps API returning no results

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API to find nearby food services, but I'm getting a response showing NO_RESULTS.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=13.06397,80.24311&radius=100&types=food&name=chennai&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBJ9werm537_N57AQ2d5RUvOwxaK-7Ajio

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show of some of your code and be more specific about what you're trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

At this time at least, it is best not to assume that Google Places has a lot of data for a location or that the data is finely categorized.

In the case of your query, I find that if I remove the `types` and `name` parameters, I get results:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=13.06397,80.24311&radius=100&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBJ9werm537_N57AQ2d5RUvOwxaK-7Ajio